# Store all possible permutations of a string in an array?

Tags: c, permutation

I want to store all the permutations of a string in a string array ...

Right now the code I'm using is :

```
# include <stdio.h>


char *pms[] = {};
int pmsi = 0;
void swap (char *x, char *y)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

void permute(char *a, int i, int n)
{
   int j;
   if (i == n) {
       pms[pmsi] = a;
       pmsi++;
   }
   else
   {
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
       {
          swap((a+i), (a+j));
          permute(a, i+1, n);
          swap((a+i), (a+j)); //backtrack
       }
   }
}

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main()
{
   char a[] = "ABC";
   permute(a, 0, 2);
   int i;
   for (i = 0 ; i < pmsi ; i++) {
       printf("%s",pms[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

But this crashes ...

I don't want to print out all the possible permutations ... I want to store them in an array.

Any fix?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this.

```
# include <stdio.h>


char *pms[];
int pmsi = 0;
void swap (char *x, char *y)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

void permute(char *a, int i, int n)
{
   int j;
   if (i == n) {
       pms[pmsi] = a;
       pmsi++;
   }
   else
   {
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
       {
          swap((a+i), (a+j));
          permute(a, i+1, n);
          swap((a+i), (a+j)); //backtrack
       }
   }
}

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main()
{
   char a[] = "ABC";
   permute(a, 0, 2);
   int i;
   for (i = 0 ; i < pmsi ; i++) {
       printf("%s",pms[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

This works

But now the permutations are not printed.. the original string is printed. Any Help ???

Comment: you are storing same address i.e of a in the pms array for all elements. you should create memory to hold these combinbations and copy each combination array instead of assignment.

Comment: Read about the difference between arrays and pointers. Also read on how array a populated in general and C-"string"s (zero-terminated `char`-arrays) in particular (see the `str*`-family of funcitons on this).

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfectly for the above motive:-

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    vector<string> pms;



    void permute(string a, int l, int r)
    {

       if (l == r) {
          pms.push_back(a);
       }
       else
      {
            for (int j = l; j <= r; j++)
            {
              swap(a[l],a[j] );
              permute(a, l+1, r);
              swap(a[l], a[j]);
            }
       }
    }


    int main()
    {
       string a = "ABC";
       permute(a, 0, 2);
       int i;
       for (i = 0 ; i < pms.size() ; i++) {
           cout<<pms[i]<<"\n";
       }
       return 0;
    }
```